# Can't send sms with Twilio, Node.js and Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, sequelize.js

I have a program which respond automatically a sms when receive an income message.

It works when I don't use Sequelize to save data to the database. But when I add the code below, the *twiml.message(msg)* is never executed.

The problem is when call twiml.message(msg) inside the *then* it doesn't work. So how to resolve this problem? Thanks

```js
Info.create(param)
    .then(info => {
      var msg = 'Numero: ' + info.id +
                ' Nom:' + info.nom +
                ' Date: ' + info.datesms);
      var twiml = new MessagingResponse();
      twiml.message(msg);
});
```

Comment: You should start by correcting the syntax error in your code.

Comment: I presume this is in an express route or something. Could you share the code for the entire route? Once I have that I feel confident I can fix it for you.